# Do to total the same elemen and to display t with paginating_find?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, Test Table

```
|id|name   |item_id|num|
|1 |apple  |1      |1  |
|2 |orenge |2      |1  |
|3 |orenge |2      |1  |
|4 |pear   |3      |1  |
|5 |apple  |1      |1  |
.....
```

In Controller,

```
@items = Test.find(:all, :page=>{:size=>20, :current=>params[:page]})
```

I use paginating_find plugin.

In view,

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<%=h item.name %> x <%= item.num %><br />
<% end %>
<%= link_to "before", {:page => @items.previous_page} if @items.previous_page? %>
<%= paginating_links(@items, :window_size => 20) %>
<%= link_to "next", {:page => @items.next_page} if @items.next_page? %>
```

↓

```
apple x 1
orenge x 1
orenge x 1
pear x 1
apple x 1

.....
```

How should I do to make it to the way below?
(The structure of the table is not changed.)

```
apple x 2
orenge x 2
pear x 1
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum with the `:group` parameter to sum the count of all items which have the same name:

```
@items = Test.sum("count", :group => "name")
```

This will give you an OrderedHash of the form `name => count`. You can then iterate over that in the view.

However it seems strange that you even have multiple items with the same name, given that there is a count column. You should probably change the code that you use to create new items, so that it only creates a new item if one with that name does not already exist - otherwise it should increment the count of the existing item.